# Upgrade from Windows 8 to 8.1, installation failed--error code 0x80004005

Tags: windows-8

I have been trying to update Windows 8 to 8.1 with no success. From the Windows store I downloaded Windows 8.1 (a free installation), and near the end of the install (90%) I get the following message:

> installation failed--error code  0x80004005.

From the Microsoft forums I concluded I needed updates KB2919355 and KB2919442 in order to install Windows 8.1, but I do not have either of these two updates and don't know where to find them.

Comment: Do you have any third party security software installed on the computer?

Comment: I searched for `KB2919355` and the first result I got was [this Microsoft document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2919355), which includes a download link.

Answer (score -1):

Go to [this page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2919355) and [this page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2919442). Scroll down to "How to obtain and install this update."  There should be some direct download links available.  Try those.